# is Celery Task initialized per each worker process, or once per app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, celery, celery-task

I have a heavy external library class which takes time to initialize and consumes a lot of memory. I want to create it once per task instance, at minimum.

```
class NlpTask(Task):
    def __init__(self):
        print('initializing NLP parser')
        self._parser = nlplib.Parser()
        print('done initializing NLP parser')

    @property
    def parser(self):
        return self._parser

@celery.task(base=NlpTask)
def my_task(arg):
    x = my_task.parser.process(arg)
    # etc.
```

Celery starts 32 worker processes, so I'd expect the printing `"initializing ... done"` 32 times, as I assume that a task instance is created per each worker. Surprisingly, I'm getting the printing *once*. What actually happens there? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your `NlpTask` is initializing once when it is getting registered with the worker.

If you have two tasks like

```
@celery.task(base=NlpTask)
def foo(arg):
    pass


@celery.task(base=NlpTask)
def bar(arg):
    pass
```

Then when you start a worker, you will see 2 initializations.

If you want to initialize it once for every worker, you can use [worker_process_init](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#worker-process-init) signal.

```
from celery.signals import worker_process_init


@worker_process_init.connect()
def setup(**kwargs):
    print('initializing NLP parser')
    # setup
    print('done initializing NLP parser')
```

Now, when you start a worker, you will see setup is being called by each process once.

Comment: that's my point - I'd expect once per worker, and it seems like once per celery instance. I edited the question

Comment: @davka Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

for this:

> that's my point - I'd expect once per worker, and it seems like once per celery instance. I edited the question – @davka

the answer must be use a sender filter in `connect`, like:

```
@worker_process_init.connect(sender='xx')
def func(sender, **kwargs):
    if sender == 'xx':
        # dosomething
```

but I found that it's not working in celery 4.0.2.